# Is there any difference between "since when did it become..." and "since when has it become..."?

Tags: difference, present-perfect, past-simple

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *since when did it become* and *since when has it become*? For example:

> Person A: I'm going to the dentist tomorrow. It's such a pleasure.
>
> Person B: Since when did it become a pleasure for you?/Since when has it become a pleasure for you?

Are both perfectly natural in the context?

Comment: See [this NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=did+it+become%2Chas+it+become&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdid%20it%20become%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20it%20become%3B%2Cc0) showing that ***did it become*** and ***has it become*** are both in common use.

Comment: Note that although using ***to do*** rather than ***to have*** as the auxiliary verb attached to ***become*** is perfectly okay in the "inverted sequence" (question-based) context, as in the example here, things aren't the same with the "standard" word order (as used in ordinary statements, with no subject/verb inversion). Thus *It has become a pleasure* is "normal", but *It did become a pleasure* only occurs in medieval / poetic contexts, OR as emphatic refutation (to disagree with someone who has just claimed that it ***didn't*** become a pleasure).

Comment: In your *exact* context there's no scope for the ***did / has*** choice to affect the meaning, but it's the same basic construction in ***Has / Did** it become legal to smoke?* In most contexts, the question being asked would be exactly the same regardless of which auxiliary verb was used (if the answer is "Yes", that means it's legal ***now***). But *in principle*, the ***did*** version there could be asking whether smoking ***was made legal at some point in the past***, even if it was subsequently made ***illegal*** again. The ***has*** version can't carry that sense.

Comment: There are tons of answers to the question of simple past versus past perfect. This is just the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm going to the dentist tomorrow. It's such a pleasure.

> Since when did it become a pleasure for you?

> Since when has it become a pleasure for you?

The present perfect version could be better as we are talking about current situation.

The preposition *since* in the examples further indicates that the change or adaptation could still be on-going.

If we want to use past tense, in a different situation, it could be

> [W]hen did it become a pleasure for you?

The subtle difference between present perfect and past simple is explained below.

> Present Perfect Simple
> Unfinished actions that started in the past and continue to the present

> Past Simple
> Finished actions

https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-or-past-simple.html